# How to call NSURLConnection delegates methods before calling UITableview delegates methods in uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I'm calling servies in `UIViewController` and also display `UITableView` in same view.I am displaying `UITableView` with json array which i'm getting from server.

My problem is, `UITableView` delegates methods is calling before `NSURLConnection` delegates methods.

I want to call `UITableView` delegates methods after calling `NSURLConnection` delegate methods.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is, after the completion of `NSURL` operation just *reload* the table view using reload method as follows:

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

whenever you want to refresh the table data or calling the `tableview delegate` methods use *reloadData* method of the table view.

if you over ridding the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods in side the same `UIViewController` you can refresh the table from this `NSURLConnectionDelegateMethod` once request is completed.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
   //Code for handling the service response here

    [yourTableView reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: I would set yourTableView's delegate right after NSURLConnection is finished, and then call reloadData.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want that uitableview delegate call after receiving response from the server, then just put this code in viewDidLoad

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad]
     tableView.delegate = nil;
     tableView.dataSource = nil;
 }
```

And after receving response just do this

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
[tableView reloadData]
```